# Precision-based Sample Size Calculation for Repeated Measures Design

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, precision

I'm looking to calculate the needed sample size for a study based on precision of estimates, but am having a very difficult time figuring out exactly how to do it. What is mainly throwing me off is

1. needing to account for measurement error and
2. needing to account for repeated measures within the same participant.

Also, I want to calculate sample size based on precision of estimates, not statistical significance.

Design: biceps muscle thickness will be measured at baseline, and then the participant will perform 8 sets of resistance training. After each set, participants will be asked to provide a subjective score of "perceived muscle swelling" and muscle thickness will be measured again. In this way, we will end up with baseline muscle thickness, as well as 8 subsequent values of both subjective muscle swelling and measured muscle thickness within each participant.

Planned analyses:

1. correlation between subjective muscle swelling scores and measured muscle swelling.
2. examine changes in both subjective scores and measured muscle thickness as more sets of resistance training are performed.

From prior research studies that also measured muscle thickness using the same device, I have gathered the typical test-retest ICC of the measurement device is ~0.988, the typical standard deviation is ~4.96, and the typical standard error of the measurement is ~0.459. I am aiming for a confidence level of 95% with precision that is higher than measurement error (that is, I want to have high confidence that if any differences between timepoints are observed, they are likely true differences rather than simply being explained by measurement error).

I'm not sure how to put all of this together into a precision-based sample size calculation. As I mentioned above, I need to account for measurement error and the repeated measures within each participant. Some reading online has also alerted me about potentially needing to account for the correlation pattern within those repeated measures, which I believe would be best described as either linear exponent autoregressive (LEAR) or first order autoregressive (AR1) in this case.

If anyone has any input or advice, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`simr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html) is your friend.